# Difference Between ASCIIEncoding and Encoding

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, asciiencoding

I understand that Encoding can be used to initialize object to perform any type of Encoding, ASCII, Unicode, UTF-8 etc. 
It appears to me that all these are sufficient for performing any kind of encoding, then what is the need for ASCIIEncoding?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `Encoding` class, in addition to being the base class of all encoders, provides static property accessors to the named subclasses.

`Encoding.ASCII` returns an instance of `ASCIIEncoding` which, in turn, subclasses `Encoding` and passes the codepage `0x4e9f` ([US-ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317756%28VS.85%29.aspx)) to the base constructor.

Comment: @Gunner - Yeah, I'd stick with accessing `Encoding.ASCII` or whatever, as it also has the benefit of being a singleton instance (they are all thread safe)