# Encoding.ASCII vs. new ASCIIEncoding()

Tags: c#, encoding, asciiencoding

If I use:

A) `var targetEncodingA = Encoding.ASCII;`

and

B) `var targetEncodingB = new ASCIIEncoding();`

then both targetEncoding0 and targetEncoding1 are of the same type.

Are there any preferred scenarios and/or advantages/disadvantages when to use A or B?

(besides creating new instance by constructor each time I use it)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference Between ASCIIEncoding and Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636372/difference-between-asciiencoding-and-encoding)

Comment: It is just a convenience property.  You'd prefer using Encoding.ASCII because it is convenient, nothing more.

Comment: @NoOne - both questions target the same specific topic still the content is slightly different. But thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the `Encoding.ASCII` implement detail (from Encoding.cs):

```
private static volatile Encoding asciiEncoding;

public static Encoding ASCII
{
  {
    if (Encoding.asciiEncoding == null)
      Encoding.asciiEncoding = (Encoding) new ASCIIEncoding();
    return Encoding.asciiEncoding;
  }
}
```

The main difference is the return type differs, which depends on what type you wish to use (`ASCIIEncoding` vs `Encoding`), and `Encoding` is the base class.

From a performance perspective, `Encoding.ASCII` is the preference.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer Encoding.ASCII in all cases, it is a static property. It avoids creating a new instance each time it is needed (singleton).

Personnaly, I avoid using the new keyword when possible when a static class can do that for you. I will add that Encoding.ASCII is shorter to write than new ASCIIEncoding().