# ASCII Encoding - one works and the other throws an error message - "Message: Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#

Let's say we have a byte array called `buff`. The first three way works just fine but the 4th way throws and exception. The only difference from the third way is that u give it the offset and length. I am not sure why the fourth way doesn't work.

```
            // First way - works
            string converted = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("converted = " + converted);
            // Second way - works
            var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(buff);
            Console.WriteLine("str = " + str);
            // Third way - works
            string ASCII = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("ASCII = " + ASCII);
            // Fourth way - doesn't work
            ASCIIEncoding asciiEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string byteCountString = asciiEncoding.GetString(buff);
```

Comment: It will help your readers immensely if you show them the exception being thrown.  For more tips on asking effective questions see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Code works for me. I think you are misreading the error, since `GetString()` does not have any "input string" (it has an input `byte[]`).  The error may be on a different line or within a different function, and you have them confused. Maybe post the exception's stack trace.

Comment: asciiEncoding doesn't contain any encoding so it will fail.  You just call the constructor but didn't add any properties.  The other 3 methods in order have following encoding 1) UTF8 2) Default 3) ASCII

Comment: @jdweng https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880556/505088

Comment: What on earth are you *trying to do*? In general, you cannot expect to take a byte array and decode it using *multiple* encodings and get any sensible results. You need to *know* the encoding used for the byte array (or attempt to apply heuristics to determine the encoding).

Comment: The error is in the title: “Message: Input string was not in a correct format”. @jdweng ah, so I have to define the encoding. @ Damien_The_Unbeliever I tried 3 other decoding just to see which works...was unclear why the 4th one failed.

Comment: The first three might work but only one or none are correct. What is the encoding used to create the bytes from text?

Comment: I personally don't see why the fourth variant fails. What is in the byte array?